# PowerPivot - Connect to Microsoft Access Database - User name & Password

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerpivot

I try to connect the protected MS-Access database to PowerPivot. On the *Table Import Wizard* form I have to enter *User name* and *Password*. Now, I don't know which user name I have to enter, because when I encrypted the database (File > Info > Encrypt Database) it asked me just for the password.

When I test the connection with just a password, it returns a *Failed to connect to the server* error.

[Table Import Wizard - Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIeGR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The password should be entered in *Advanced* on *Jet OLEDB: Database Password*.

[image: Advanced Form]